# Getting id of a swiped list element Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html-lists, swipe

I cannot seem to get the id of the list item swiped!

See the Code here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD82HCGZJ2PE

```js
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
  $("li, ul").on("swipe",function(){
  alert(event.target.id);
   });                       
});
</script>
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
<h1>The swipe Event</h1>
  </div>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-divider-theme="a" data-count-theme="a">
<li data-role="list-divider">Pick Ups <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>

<li id="B3">
  <a href'ride_details.php?TripID=15'>
    <h2 id="h2">Some Rider</h2>
    <p><strong>555 code lane Freedy, Texas 75035</strong></p>
    <p>Jon Doe</p>
  </a>
</li>  
<li id="B3"><a href'ride_details.php?TripID=15' id="2">
  <h2>Some Rider</h2>
  <p><strong>555 code lane Freedy, Texas 75035</strong></p>
  <p>Jon Doe</p>
  </a>
</li>   
  
  <div data-role="footer">
<h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, most of the times, the `event.target` is not the `li`, but one of its child element.

There was other mistakes:

1- The `event` wasn't passed to the handler function.

this: `$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){`
should be: `$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(event){`

2- You can't use the same `id` on multiple elements.

3- There was an `</ul>` missing.

And I've added an exclusion for the first `li` to trigger on this (the "Pick Ups" line).

**So in the snippet below**, if you look at the console, you will see the `event.target.tagName` which triggered the event AND the `id` of the parent `li` which handles it.

Using `$(this)` on the `li` enables you to catch the event that was triggered by one of its child.

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
  $("ul li").not(":first").on("swipe",function(event){
    console.log("event target element: "+event.target.tagName);
    console.log("li id: "+$(this).attr("id") );
  });                       
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>



<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>The swipe Event</h1>
  </div>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-divider-theme="a" data-count-theme="a">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Pick Ups <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>

    <li id="firstRider"><a href'ride_details.php?TripID=15'>
      <h2 id="h2">First Rider</h2>
      <p><strong>555 code lane
        Freedy, Texas 75035</strong></p>
      <p>Jon Doe</p>
      </a>
    </li>  
    <li id="secondRider"><a href'ride_details.php?TripID=15' id="2">
      <h2>Second Rider</h2>
      <p><strong>555 code lane
        Freedy, Texas 75035</strong></p>
      <p>Jon Doe</p>
      </a>
    </li>   
  </ul>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```